# Get a round dollar amounts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find transactions with round dollar amounts (e.g 200.0000, 5.0000, 1350.0000).

SQL sever Amount column is NUMERIC(38.4) type.

How do I convert it and what function do I need to apply after?

Comment: In the US 200.0000 does not make sense since we use `.` as the fractional separator.  This makes me unsure what you want.  Do you not want any fraction?

Comment: These are dollar amounts....$200.00 , $5.00 and $1350.00 . Column name is Amount

Comment: so you want dollars and cents? i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find values with no decimals

```
Select * 
 From  YourTable
 where Val = floor(Val)
```

> **EDIT - Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Val decimal(10,4))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(100.25),
(5.00),
(100.00)

Select * 
 From  @YourTable
 where Val/100 = floor(Val/100)
```

**Returns**

```
100.0000
```

Comment: Thanks John. What if also need last two digits to be zeros like $200.00?

Comment: @SirOliver where Val/100 = floor(Val/100)

Comment: no, you want CAST(field as NUMERIC(x,2)) that will give you to digits to the right of the decimal.

Comment: @Hogan Not sure I agree.  OP was looking for "nice" round numbers - See Edit - Example

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- huh?  He shows what he wants right there in the first comment?

Comment: @Hogan I suspect you were over-thinking it. Not being burdened with a high intellect, my lizard brain had a different understanding.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - what is this "over-thinking" you speak of?  Isn't that an oxymoron, surely such a thing is not possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just check the column against it's truncation.

```
Select *
From Table
Where Amount = Cast(Amount as Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want but if you don't want any fraction then just cast to an integer like this:

```
SELECT CAST(COLUMN_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY AS INTEGER) AS Result
FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DID_NOT_SAY
```